# Feeding numpy array to Tensorflow gives TypeError

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I am trying to classify digits on MNIST using Tensorflow and Python.
I am getting an error while feeding numpy arrays to feed_dict in this line -

```
x = tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.float32, shape = (None, 784))  
y_correct = tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.float32, shape = (None, 10))  
sess.run(train_step, feed_dict = {x: batch_xs, y_correct: batch_ys})
```

The error is TypeError : UnhashableType: 'numpy.ndarray'

I confirmed the shapes of batch_xs and batch_ys and they are (100, 784) and (100, 10), 100 is my batch-size.
Also, same code is running when I tried to run the example given in Tensorflow tutorials, and there batch_xs and batch_ys are 'numpy.ndarray'.

I would really appreciate some help here. Thanks.

Comment: that error happens when key of a dictionary is unhashable, so either `x` or `y_correct` is numpy array

Comment: Can you provide the entire code for the train_step operation??? Need more information to see what is happening with your code.. But in general you can feed numpy arrays into the placeholder variables